# How to make if / else if into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, request, uri

I have to add noindex to some url's, this is my code at the moment:

```
<?php if ($metanoindex) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
<?php } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/dolls/1/bestselling' ) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
<?php } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/dolls/1/bestselling/30' ) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" /> 
<?php } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/dolls/1' ) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" /> 
<?php } else { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<?php } ?>
```

I wondered if there is a way to make an array of urls instead of repeating "else if" each time.

Comment: Take a look at the functionn is in_array of PHP: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below

```
<?php
    $arr = array('/dolls/1/bestselling','/dolls/1/bestselling/30','/dolls/1');
    if($metanoindex || in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$arr)){ ?>
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" /> 
<?php
    }
    else {
?>
      <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<?php } ?>
```

PHP Manual: [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Use `if ($metanoindex || in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $array))` instead .. look at the question again

Comment: It ok .. that is why i deleted my answer to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = array('/dolls/1/bestselling', '/dolls/1/bestselling/30', '/dolls/1');
if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $urls)) {
    // Insert meta tag here
}
```